# Add Spacer Tile to Mac 10.9.3

Tags: macos, dock

Since receiving a new Macbook with 10.9.3 installed, I have not been able to create spacer tiles in the Dock.

Running the following commands normal and sudo yield no result:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{"tile-type"="spacer-tile";}'
killall Dock
```

Is this an issue with 10.9.3?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but this morning, when I booted up the machine, I had like 10 spacer-tiles in the dock. This may be that "killall Dock" isn't actually resetting it until I hard shutdown.